# Microstrategy Create attribute Previoux months from YYYYMM format

Tags: date, microstrategy

I'm newbie on Microstrategy.
I've an Excel file for dataset input.
In this file, I have attributes like products, months (YYYYMM), and some measures.
To my report, I need to compare M vs M-1 vs M-12.
Is it possible to create a new attribute in the dataset like M-1.

I tried `AddMonths(Concat(SubStr(moisno@ID;1;4);"/";SubStr(moisno@ID;5;2);"/01");-1)` but the YYYYMM seems not to be recognize.

Thanks for your help.
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

I found this trick.
`ToNumber(ToString<Pattern=yyyyMM>(AddMonths(ToDateTime<Pattern=yyyyMM>(Concat(ToString(moisno@ID);"01"));1)))`

What do you thing about that ?

Regards.
Jérôme

Answer (score 0):

I also acheive this with the LAG function

`Lag<BreakBy={@p}, SortBy=(moisno@ID)>([Sum Nb Cli];1;ZeroToNull(0))`

Regards.
Jérôme